# Resource-efficient finding ONE possible combinations of numbers to reach a given sum

Tags: ruby, dynamic-programming

I am using these algorithms in Ruby:

```
  def subset_sum(inp, s)
        arr = []
        loop.with_index{|_, i| arr << inp.combination(i+1).to_a.find{
    |c| (c.inject(0) {|sum,x| sum + x})  == s}; break if !a.none? || i == inp.count }
    arr
  end

  subset_sum([1,2,3,4,5,6], 15)
```

and

```
  def subset_sum(*args)
    args[0].length.downto(1).flat_map do |i|
      args[0].combination(i).to_a
    end.select do |a|
      a.inject(:+) == args[1]
    end
  end
  
  subset_sum([1,2,3,4,5,6], 15).first
```

Unfortunately, both paths are resource intensive. If I increment the incoming array, the computation takes a long time. Tell me, is there an optimal Ruby-way to solve this problem?

Comment: Replace `select` by `detect` (or `find`). It stops the search when it finds one.

Comment: Also `.inject(:+)` can be written as `.sum`, but don't expect a speedup.

Comment: Are the elements of the given array known to be non-negative?

Comment: Cary, thanks a lot for your decision. This works great...
The answer to your question is 'yes'. I'm building a simple ATM on Grape, so all the elements of the array are non-negative. My solution is primitive, but I've never worked with Grape before. This is my 'try-out': [link](https://github.com/cmirnow/atm-on-grape/blob/master/app/services/calculations.rb)

I didn't want to waste your time with my stupidity. But, if you have a couple of minutes of free time, I would be very grateful for any comments and options for your code. Thank you.

Comment: @CarySwoveland , please take a look. The method returns nil: `subset_sum([1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 10], 6) #=> nil`

Comment: Alexi, please have a look now.

Comment: @CarySwoveland , I think, new version of code has a typo? `syntax error, unexpected end-of-input, expecting `end''

Comment: I can't reproduce your error message. Please double-check.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I understand all the elements of the array are non-negative.

Try the following recursion.

```
def subset_sum((first, *rest), target)
  return (first == target ? [first] : nil) if rest.empty?
  rv = subset_sum(rest, target)
  return rv unless rv.nil?
  return nil if first > target
  return [first] if first == target
  rv = subset_sum(rest, target-first)
  rv.nil? ? nil : [first, *rv]
end
```

```
arr = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
subset_sum([1,2,3,4,5,6], 15)
  #=> [4,5,6]
arr1 = arr.shuffle
  #=> [5, 3, 6, 4, 2, 1]
subset_sum(arr1, 15)
  #=> [3, 6, 4, 2]
subset_sum([1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 10], 6)
  #=> [1, 5]
```

In the first example a solution is found rather quickly, but that is only because the last three elements of the array sum to `11`. By contrast, when the elements of `arr` are shuffled, to produce `arr1`, it takes considerably longer to execute.

---

To see what's happening let's include some `puts` statements.

```
def subset_sum((first, *rest), target)
  puts "first = #{first}, rest = #{rest}, target = #{target}"
  if rest.empty?
    puts "  rest is empty, return #{first == target ? [first] : nil}"        
    return first == target ? [first] : nil
  end 
  rv = subset_sum(rest, target)
  puts "  rv #{first} not used"
  puts "  return #{rv}" unless rv.nil?
  return rv unless rv.nil?
  return nil if first > target
  return [first] if first == target
  rv = subset_sum(rest, target-first)
  rv.nil? ? nil : [first, *rv]
end
```

```
subset_sum(arr1, 15)
first = 5, rest = [3, 6, 4, 2, 1], target = 15
first = 3, rest = [6, 4, 2, 1], target = 15
first = 6, rest = [4, 2, 1], target = 15
first = 4, rest = [2, 1], target = 15
first = 2, rest = [1], target = 15
first = 1, rest = [], target = 15
  rest is empty, return 
  rv 2 not used
first = 1, rest = [], target = 13
  rest is empty, return 
  rv 4 not used
first = 2, rest = [1], target = 11
first = 1, rest = [], target = 11
  rest is empty, return 
  rv 2 not used
first = 1, rest = [], target = 9
  rest is empty, return 
  rv 6 not used
first = 4, rest = [2, 1], target = 9
first = 2, rest = [1], target = 9
first = 1, rest = [], target = 9
  rest is empty, return 
  rv 2 not used
first = 1, rest = [], target = 7
  rest is empty, return 
  rv 4 not used
first = 2, rest = [1], target = 5
first = 1, rest = [], target = 5
  rest is empty, return 
  rv 2 not used
first = 1, rest = [], target = 3
  rest is empty, return 
  rv 3 not used
first = 6, rest = [4, 2, 1], target = 12
first = 4, rest = [2, 1], target = 12
first = 2, rest = [1], target = 12
first = 1, rest = [], target = 12
  rest is empty, return 
  rv 2 not used
first = 1, rest = [], target = 10
  rest is empty, return 
  rv 4 not used
first = 2, rest = [1], target = 8
first = 1, rest = [], target = 8
  rest is empty, return 
  rv 2 not used
first = 1, rest = [], target = 6
  rest is empty, return 
  rv 6 not used
first = 4, rest = [2, 1], target = 6
first = 2, rest = [1], target = 6
first = 1, rest = [], target = 6
  rest is empty, return 
  rv 2 not used
first = 1, rest = [], target = 4
  rest is empty, return 
  rv 4 not used
first = 2, rest = [1], target = 2
first = 1, rest = [], target = 2
  rest is empty, return 
  rv 2 not used
  rv 5 not used
  return [3, 6, 4, 2]
#=> [3, 6, 4, 2]
```

In general I'm not confident this will be significantly faster than using `Array#combination`, but one might do some benchmarks.

---

Further improvement could be obtained using dynamic programming. The state variables would be the sum of the variables used among the first `n` elements of the array. For example, if the first four elements were

```
a4 = [1,2,3,4]
```

then all the combinations of between 1 and 4 elements would be:

```
all = (1..4).each_with_object([]) do |n,a|
  a4.combination(n).each { |aa| a << aa.sum }
end
  #=> [1, 2, 3, 4, 3, 4, 5, 5, 6, 7, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
```

The possible values of the state variable for the first 4 elements would be the unique values of this array:

```
all_uniq = all.uniq
  #=> [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
```

and if the values of the array were known to all be non-negative, and if the target value were, say, 6, the possible values of that state variable would be limited to the following.

```
all.uniq.select { |a| a <= 5 }
  #=> [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

This would be done efficiently, with the calculations done for `a4` being derived from the results for `a3`, and so on.

If desired, I could show how a dynamic programming solution could be written.

Answer (score 0):

```rb
def find_one_subset_sum(inp, sum)
  candidates = inp.filter { |i| i < sum } # don't do this optimize if inp contain negative numbers
  sum_combi_hash = Hash.new do |hash, key|
    if key > 0
      hash[key] = {candidates[key] => [candidates[key]]}
      if hash[key - 1][sum].nil?
        hash[key - 1].each do |s, c|
          hash[key][s] = c
          new_s = s + candidates[key]
          next unless hash[key][new_s].nil?
          hash[key][new_s] = c + [candidates[key]]
          break if new_s == sum
        end
      else
        hash[key][sum] = hash[key - 1][sum]
      end
      hash[key]
    else
      hash[key] = {candidates.first => [candidates.first]}
    end
  end
  sum_combi_hash[candidates.size - 1][sum]
end
```